# Cannot search cocoapods on any browser (2 computes)

Tags: cocoapods

Anyone else having trouble searching cocoapods?  This is Aprip 19 2018

2aws-search.cocoapods.org/api/v1/pods.picky.hash.json?query=pictures&ids=20&offset=0&sort=quality Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 ()
cocoapods.org/:1 Failed to load https://aws-search.cocoapods.org/api/v1/pods.picky.hash.json?query=pictures&ids=20&offset=0&sort=quality: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://cocoapods.org' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 504.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using http://cocoapods.wantedly.com while cocoapods.org is not working.
I have the same problem.

Or you can use terminal:

> pod search alamofire --simple